# Identify slow code to optimize build time

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm using these **Compilation Swift Flag** to identify codes that slow down the compilation time:

```
-Xfrontend -warn-long-function-bodies=100
-Xfrontend -warn-long-expression-type-checking=100
```

Then after building, I get `warnings` like these:

`Instance method 'startFadePositionTitle()' took 2702ms to type-check (limit: 500ms)`

for this part of the code:

```
    func startFadePositionTitle() -> CGFloat {
        let value: CGFloat = ((backgroundImage.frame.height/2 - contentTitle.frame.height/2) - navbarView.frame.height)/2
        return value
    }
```

Can someone explains me what is wrong in this method and what could I possibly improve?

Comment: I’d read this if I were you. https://forums.swift.org/t/is-xfrontend-forbidding-enough/18791 This is not for general consumption.

Comment: Just an observation, you can simplify this to `((backgroundImage.frame.height - contentTitle.frame.height)/2 - navbarView.frame.height)/2`

Comment: Start by optimizing your architecture instead of microoptimizations for specific lines of code. If you split your code base to frameworks (modules), you won't have to solve such problems.

Comment: @Sulthan in fact, such issues can generate a lot of extra compile time. You shouldn't call them micro. :)

Comment: First of all try to split this long line into 2-3 smaller expressions. I believe the problem here is 2 without type.

Comment: @TimurBernikovich That's true but the issue with type inferring is that the more types, the more compiler difficulty. Splitting the project can improve the performance of compiling individual functions.
Also note that the worst problem when compiling is when a file has to be compiled multiple times due to bidirectional dependencies between files. If you keep dependencies unidirectional, you won't have such problems. However, that's hard to do without actually splitting the project into independent modules. That's why splitting helps so much.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but I can't help recommending this code https://github.com/RobertGummesson/BuildTimeAnalyzer-for-Xcode to anyone who needs to understand build-time issues in their code. Really neat (I'm not related to the developer)

Comment: @Alex Thanks for the link, it's really interesting... Though after further investigation I've notice the issue might be in my objc files... Not sure why though

Comment: @Jaythaking. Of course there are multiple reasons for the slow compiling issue but you should work on them **one by one** and not **all at once**. The update you provided is completely different topic from the original question and you should try to enhance it specifically with more attention.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should break it to smaller chunks, then Swift can do type check more easily. Also the more you tell, the less Swift has to think. So you can help compiler and tell it anything you already know:

```
func beginFadePositionTitle() -> CGFloat {
    let n: CGFloat = 2
    let a: CGFloat = self.backgroundImage.frame.height/n
    let b: CGFloat = self.contentTitle.frame.height/n
    let ab: CGFloat = a - b
    let c: CGFloat = self.navbarView.frame.height
    let abc: CGFloat = ab - c
    return abc/n
}
```

> Instance method 'beginFadePositionTitle()' took **1ms** to type-check (limit: 1ms)

This is the result when you tell everything to compiler. See the difference?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to try this one

```
func startFadePositionTitle() -> CGFloat {
    return ((backgroundImage.frame.height - contentTitle.frame.height)/2.0 - 
           navbarView.frame.height)/2.0
}
```

with my Xcode 11.2 / Catalina (tested assuming that all those `frame`s are `CGRect`s), there is no such warning with those compiler flags. In the corner case it is possible to use `CGFloat(2.0)` in corresponding places, but I think it is superfluous.

Answer (score 1):

You are calculating *value* every time when you call this method *startFadePositionTitle*

You can specify that once and after than you can use freely.

```
let value: CGFloat = ((backgroundImage.frame.height/2 - contentTitle.frame.height/2) - navbarView.frame.height)/2
```

Use that in *viewDidLoad* method

And optimize your code like that

```
func startFadePositionTitle() -> CGFloat {
    return value
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Floating point division and square root take considerably longer to compute than addition and multiplication. The latter two are computed directly while the former are usually computed with an iterative algorithm. The most common approach is to use a division-free Newton-Raphson iteration to get an approximation to the reciprocal of the denominator (division) or the reciprocal square root, and then multiply by the numerator (division) or input argument (square root).

Source :
[Why is float division slow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/506237/why-is-float-division-slow)

So i have made it to one division:

```
((x - y)/2 - z)/2 = (x-y-2z)/4
```

i.e. You can just write something like this

```
 (backgroundImage.frame.height - contentTitle.frame.height - 2.0*navbarView.frame.height)/4.0
```

So small change to function would be something like this

```
func startFadePositionTitle() -> CGFloat {
    return (backgroundImage.frame.height - contentTitle.frame.height - 2.0*navbarView.frame.height)/4.0
}
```

Comment: It's interesting but the slow compilation seemed to be related to the type casting more than the actual operation time from my test.