# Why are swift function being compiled 25 times?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, build

I've realised that my iOS project (quite large, only swift code) is taking a very long time to build, so I started analysing the code build time using `-debug-time-function-bodies` and checking the transcript logs.

I noticed that a lot of my functions are getting compiled 25 or 26 times.

What can be causing this kind of issue?

To make this question easier to understand here's a screenshot from [BuildTimeAnalyzer for Xcode](https://github.com/RobertGummesson/BuildTimeAnalyzer-for-Xcode)

[image]

As you can see under `occurrences` some functions are built 25 or 26 times.

Comment: I assume that "Build Active Architecture Only" is set to "Yes" on debug builds, right?

Comment: Yes, that's correct

Comment: That screenshot is pretty much useless :|

Comment: Could those be different specializations of the same generic function?

Comment: Re/ the screenshot, it just redacted the class names and function names. None are generic functions. The screenshot is used to demonstrate the number of occurrences. Which is the main point of this question

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The data you provided is not enough to tell what is the actual cause but I'm going to summarize some possibilities.

### What is the meaning of occurrence?

It means the compiler is type checking a method or property or expression multiple times.

---

### How should I know what and where is that method and how much time exactly it takes?

By enabling these two flags you can see them directly in code:

```
-Xfrontend -warn-long-expression-type-checking=100
```

```
-Xfrontend -warn-long-function-bodies=100
```

---

### What is that `100` in the flags?

That is the minimum time you aware. You can start with higher number and lowering it step by step after fixing more expensive issues.

---

### How can I fix that?

By telling the compiler what you already know instead of letting it infer itself. for example:

```
let singleString = myStrings.joined(separator: ";") /* takes around 200ms to compile */
let singleTypedString: String = myStrings.joined(separator: ";") /* Takes just 1ms to compile */
```

As you can see, writing `String` type will eliminate `199 ms` (on this moment)

<sub>you can find a more complicated example [here in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59041458/5623035) where simple changes in code save about **2700ms !**</sub>

---

### Why the compiler doing it over and over?

Seems like some changes in newer Xcode versions, (*I think* one of them is the parallel building or etc.) caused this. LLDB and Swift language developers are working hard to boost the performance but we can help us ourselves.

### Is there any workaround for preventing multiple type checking?

Depending on the source of the issue (variable, function, closure, lazy, etc.) there are some ways to enhance it. For example:

Making everything `final` and better than that, make them `private` where possible. This is how the compiler knows you are not going to `override` it, so it can type check just once.

This is how you can reduce your build time and prevent the compiler from type checking multiple times.

Hope it helps.

---

---

## One more thing!:

According to [this link in Swift.org](https://forums.swift.org/t/is-xfrontend-forbidding-enough/18791):

> `-Xfrontend`, which prompted this post. Every front-end argument is considered unstable. **All of them**. Even the ones that are the same as driver options. I'd really like to rename this but I don't know what to rename it too. (And to make matters worse, Xcode currently uses it for something. You don't want to know.)

So 1st, make sure you are using these flags only in DEBUG mode, And 2nd, turn them off after fixing the issues you were looking for and try them from time to time.

Comment: can you tell how to use these flags in only DEBUG mode?